# Logrotate using rsyslog's omprog hangs over time

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate

Tried almost everything, but still cant find any solution for the issue so wanted to ask for little help in such case:

I have got logrotate (v. 3.7.8) configured based on size of log files:

```
/home/test/logs/*.log {
  missingok
  notifempty
  nodateext
  size 10k
  rotate 100
  copytruncate
}
```

Rotation of logs is based only on size, invoked whenever message will arrived to rsyslog deamon (v. 5.8.10). Configuration of rsyslog:

```
$ModLoad omprog
$ActionOMProgBinary /usr/local/bin/log_rotate.sh
$MaxMessageSize 64k

$ModLoad imuxsock
$ModLoad imklog
$ModLoad imtcp

$InputTCPServerRun 514

$template FORMATTER, "%HOSTNAME% | %msg:R,ERE,4,FIELD:(.*)\s(.*)(:::)(.*)--end%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate FORMATTER

$Escape8BitCharactersOnReceive off
$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off

$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0
$SystemLogRateLimitBurst 0

$FileOwner test
$FileGroup test
$DirOwner test
$DirGroup test

# Log each module execution to separate log files and don't use the prepending module_execution_ in the log name.
$template CUSTOM_LOGS,"/home/test/logs/%programname:R,ERE,1,FIELD:^module_execution_(.*)--end%.log"
if $programname startswith 'module_execution_' then :omprog:
if $programname startswith 'module_execution_' then ?CUSTOM_LOGS
& ~
```

Script invoked by the omprog just runs logrotate and for test purpose sends new line to logrot file:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "1" >> /home/test/logrot
 /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf -v
```

How to reproduce:

- execute:

  for i in {1..50000}; do logger -t "module_execution_test" "test message"; done;
- check rotate files - there will be a lot of files test.log.1,2,3 etc. with size near to the 10kB and one test.log with size much bigger then predicted
- check:

  wc -l /home/test/logrot
  It will be growing for some time but then stops even if the messages still arrives (hangs exactly in the time when rotation stops to happen) - it means that rsyslog doesnt call external script anymore

So IMO it looks like a bug in rsyslog or omprog plugin. Any idea what is going on?

br

Comment: Was reported to rhel support. Rsyslog 8.23 doesnt have this bug so its propably bug in rsyslog or omprog plugin. I will add some comments when will be sure what was the root cause